# How to set Unicode character as Text of TextBlock in the code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, unicode

I have decided to use UPWARDS WHITE ARROW WITHIN TRIANGLE ARROWHEAD character as describes here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f895/index.htm

Following vb.net code is okey.

```
TextBlock1.Text = Convert.ToChar(&H25B2)
```

But following vb.net code is not okey.

```
TextBlock1.Text = Convert.ToChar(&#x1f895;)
```

Any solution?

Comment: *All* strings in .NET are Unicode. The page you see now is Unicode - SO is an ASP.NET site. What you typed is just invalid syntax. You can simply copy the characters you want and paste them inside a string, eg 

Comment: BTW the page you linked to contains the escape codes too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in .NET are Unicode. You could just type that character (or rather, paste it) in a string:

```
var x1="";
```

To display it though, your application or console would need a font with the proper glyph. You'd also have to make sure you save your source file as UTF8.

The page you linked to contains the escape sequence(s) you need to use in C/C++/Java *and* C# to create the same character:

```
var x2="\uD83E\uDC95";
Debug.Assert(x2==x1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me *\U0001F895* works:

```
Console.WriteLine("\U0001F895");
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1c13nZ)